# Uniroot function in C

Tags: c, r

In a C program that gets called from within R, I need to use the 'uniroot' function of R. One way to do this is to invoke R again from C with the 'call_R' function. I am wondering if there is a better way ? Is there a function in 'Rmath.h'to do this ?

Comment: For those who know C, but not R, you should tell what `uniroot` does.

Comment: Those who know C, but not R, should probably move along to some other question as I will do now.

Comment: why not just grab the `uniroot` source code and port it to C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per `?uniroot`, the R function is basically a wrapper around some freely available C source code for implementing Richard Brent's root finding algorithm -- it even gives the [link](https://www.netlib.org/c/brent.shar). So if you're already programming in C, you don't need to touch R at all for this.

Comment: This answers my question perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `Rmath` library provides a number statistical distribution functions, but no access to R itself.

What you want amounts to embedding R in your C program, which is doable but a little tedious.  If you are to C++, you could look at my [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) which makes this pretty painless via C++.  It comes with a fairly decent number of examples.